# OCR code that rotates image 90º 4 times fails when image is already right side up

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have written Python code using PyTesseract to extract text from images that may be rotated. It does this by trying to get the text from the base image, then turning it 90 degrees three times and comparing the confidence of the text detected from each image. It then picks the image with the highest confidence score and prints the text.

When I give it images that have already been rotated sideways or upside down, it works (correctly extracts the text). But when I give it images that are right side up it's not able to figure out what the text is. What's going wrong?

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

myconfig = r"--psm 6 --oem 3"

# Replace with your image file path
img = cv2.imread("lib\math\one (un).jpg")

# Create a function to find the best rotation angle
def find_best_rotation(image):
    confidences = []
    for angle in [0, 90, 180, 270]:
        rotated_image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE if angle == 90 else cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE if angle == 270 else cv2.ROTATE_180)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(rotated_image, config=myconfig)
        confidences.append((angle, len(text.strip())))

    best_rotation, _ = max(confidences, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return best_rotation

best_rotation = find_best_rotation(img)

# Rotate the image to the best rotation
best_rotated_image = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE if best_rotation == 90 else cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE if best_rotation == 270 else cv2.ROTATE_180)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(best_rotated_image, config=myconfig)

print(f"Best rotation angle: {best_rotation} degrees")
print("Text extracted from the image:")
print(text)
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I edited the title and question to clarify. This already is an MRE, though. Copy and paste the asker's code and give it any image of text, then try it again after rotating and saving the test image; you can see the behavior described.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what this code does:

```
for angle in [0, 90, 180, 270]:
    rotated_image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE if angle == 90 else cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE if angle == 270 else cv2.ROTATE_180)
```

- If `angle` is `90`, the image is rotated 90º clockwise.
- If `angle` is `270`, the image is rotated 90º counterclockwise.
- Otherwise, the image is rotated 180º.

This means that even if `angle` is `0`, you're still going to flip it upside down. This means you never actually analyze the image in the original orientation. So if you supply an image that's already right-side up, the OCR fails.

What about something like this instead?

```
rotation_codes = {
        None: 0,
        cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE: 90,
        cv2.ROTATE_180: 180,
        cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE: 270, 
    }

    for code in rotation_codes:
        rotated_image = cv2.rotate(image, code) if code is not None else image
```

You can then retrieve the correct numerical angle with `rotation_codes[rotation]`.

Note: you're doing extra work by rotating and analyzing the image again at the end. You've already done that, just save and use the text you extracted during the loop. You're also not actually checking any kind of confidence score, just picking the longest text extracted (although from trying it out, that seems to be a surprisingly accurate heuristic).